# Do I need to leave SPF TXT record for backwards compatibility?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, spf

There is a dedicated DNS SPF record which can be used for SPF record. However DNS TXT record may also be used for backwards compatibility.

If i CAN define SPF record - should i just delete the deprecated TXT record or leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually following [RFC 7208, section 3.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.1) you should only be using the TXT type record:

> SPF records MUST be published as a DNS TXT (type 16) Resource Record
> (RR) [RFC1035] only.  The character content of the record is encoded
> as [US-ASCII].  Use of alternative DNS RR types was supported in
> SPF's experimental phase but has been discontinued.

The SPF RR type has been deprecated by the SPFbis working group in April 2014. Reasoning for this can also be found in [RFC 7208, section 3.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.1), which obsoletes the older [RFC 4408](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408):

> In 2003, when SPF was first being developed, the requirements for
> assignment of a new DNS RR type were considerably more stringent than
> they are now.  Additionally, support for easy deployment of new DNS
> RR types was not widely deployed in DNS servers and provisioning
> systems.  As a result, developers of SPF found it easier and more
> practical to use the TXT RR type for SPF records.

Comment: "I am become Time, the destroyer of worlds."

Comment: A-ha, time has passed and this is now a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I chose to leave mine.  It doesn't cost anything, and may continue to work.

Revisit this in a few years when more servers/clients have updated, and if you can, see who is asking for the TXT record perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 7208 is a bad proposal that should not be adopted.  Today ( 2019), my DNS servers still see queries for SPF type 99 records, so clearly there are other people who ignore the incorrect conclusions reached in that RFC and in 6686.

Comment: Is your rationale that because a very few people are stuck in the past that everyone should remain stuck in the past? That's kind of how this situation arose to begin with.